# Slow mongodb query for just 200 simple records in collection , query optimization

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, database-performance

I have mongodb collection called "product" which contains following type of documents:

```
{
    "_id" : "64a1583ab9ec356358be7853",
    "productId" : Long("7"),
    "name" : "The LG 7 kg 5 Star Semi-Automatic Top Loading Washing Machine (P7020NGAZ)",
    "description" : "The LG 7 kg 5 Star Semi-Automatic Top Loading Washing Machine is designed to handle a 7 kg laundry load, making it suitable for small to medium-sized households. It features a top-loading design, allowing for easy loading and unloading of clothes. \r\n\r\nBrand  ‎LG\r\nModel   P7020NGAZ\r\nCapacity  ‎7 Kilograms\r\nMaximum Rotational Speed   ‎1300 RPM\r\nInstallation Type   ‎Free Standing\r\nPart Number   20NGAZ\r\nForm Factor  ‎Stand alone\r\nSpecial Features   ‎Wind Jet Dry, Collar Scrubber, Rat Away Technology, Rust Free Plastic Base\r\nControl Console   ‎Knob\r\nNumber of Option Cycles  3\r\nAccess Location   ‎Top Load\r\nVoltage   ‎230 Volts\r\nWattage   ‎360 Watts\r\nCertification   ‎Energy Star\r\nMaterial   Plastic\r\nBatteries Included   ‎No\r\nBatteries Required   No\r\nManufacturer   ‎LG Electronics India Pvt. Ltd.\r\nCountry of Origin   ‎India",
    "photos" : [
        "https://electrotrade-uploads.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/photos/product/mlri14107249018289122.jpg",
        "https://electrotrade-uploads.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/photos/product/tl5714107248740599521.jpg",
        "https://electrotrade-uploads.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/photos/product/kj0z14107248662853011.jpg"
    ],
    "price" : 10800.0,
    "sellingPrice" : 10800.0,
    "weight" : 0.0,
    "reward" : 25.0,
    "gstPercentage" : 4.5,
    "minQty" : 1,
    "maxQty" : 100,
    "totalStockAvailable" : 150,
    "featuredProduct" : true,
    "sku" : "",
    "categoryId" : Long("2"),
    "sellerId" : Long("7"),
    "subCategoryId" : Long("16"),
    "brand" : DBRef("brand", "64a06d723eaf681bbc77e165"),
    "user" : {
        "_id" : "64a122f6b9ec356358be7848",
        "email" : "kushaljain1256@gmail.com",
        "username" : "Kushalj",
        "password" : "{bcrypt}$2a$10$lbwmsJ.gP74thXP/HGbp7O9I6kZnzy.2NSfM5Gmx2U5HRS/9SdDRa",
        "firstName" : "Kushal ",
        "lastName" : "Jain",
        "phoneNumber" : "8005812294",
        "userId" : Long("7"),
        "pincode" : "304001",
        "address" : "Sharma Colony, Tonk",
        "city" : "Tonk",
        "state" : "Rajasthan",
        "pancard" : "undefined",
        "aadhar" : "undefined",
        "businessName" : "Rajasthan Electronics",
        "businessType" : "Electronics & Electrical ",
        "walletBalance" : 50.0,
        "active" : true,
        "mobileVerified" : true,
        "emailVerified" : true,
        "subscribed" : false,
        "referralCode" : "o5be9b",
        "deviceDetail" : {
            "deviceToken" : "ekj5ioLhRXmcrk3nztNfnH:APA91bGoak8zfrW-x3Di-rr2PjQ-sIVYh_jCSgBeWj53sC0ytmndKH7YrTgoRwkb5RfVDyBf2iYeysOCMhNNtgzkvb-RBHyTsz8xKgOLWdGBD8xXwQEf4h0nJXdGQy6ZwSvle2tYb08g",
            "deviceType" : "android",
            "os" : "android",
            "osVersion" : "11",
            "appVersion" : "1.8",
            "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2023-08-03T09:39:26.527+0000")
        },
        "isReferred" : false,
        "isPushEnabled" : true,
        "roles" : [
            DBRef("role", "649fbe99196ccf0b66ba0398"),
            DBRef("role", "64a123adb9ec356358be784c")
        ],
        "categories" : [
            DBRef("category", "64a0598e3eaf681bbc77e160"),
            DBRef("category", "64a057ce3eaf681bbc77e15f"),
            DBRef("category", "64a05a323eaf681bbc77e161"),
            DBRef("category", "64a05b8d3eaf681bbc77e162"),
            DBRef("category", "64a05d563eaf681bbc77e163"),
            DBRef("category", "64a0ffa73eaf681bbc77e168"),
            DBRef("category", "64a1022e3eaf681bbc77e169"),
            DBRef("category", "64c7ad26ef0147741249e205"),
            DBRef("category", "64c7adabef0147741249e206"),
            DBRef("category", "64c7a66aef0147741249e204")
        ],
        "displayName" : "BO-7",
        "createDate" : ISODate("2023-07-02T07:10:46.044+0000"),
        "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2023-07-31T12:53:29.658+0000")
    },
    "note" : "null",
    "shipping" : {
        "shippingType" : "ORDER_AMOUNT",
        "amount" : 40.0,
        "minAmount" : 80.0,
        "maxAmount" : 120.0,
        "shippingAllIndia" : true,
        "minWeight" : 0.0,
        "maxWeight" : 0.0,
        "range" : 0.0,
        "createDate" : ISODate("2023-08-01T16:21:15.493+0000"),
        "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2023-08-01T16:21:15.493+0000")
    },
    "active" : true,
    "createDate" : ISODate("2023-07-02T10:58:02.455+0000"),
    "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2023-08-03T15:29:16.697+0000"),
    "_class" : "com.electrotrade.model.Product"
}
```

I have around only 200 documents so far but when I query the document using Java spring boot mongo data as below query,

```
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {

    List<Product> findAll();
    
}
```

it takes more than **62 seconds**  to fetch those 200 records.
The DBRef fields are only of 4-5 simple String type fields in their own collection like for example "Brand" in this case.

Can someone please help me how i should optimize the fetching to be more efficient as I am 100% sure that this is not the expected time for mere 200 records for mongodb to fetch.
Should be hardly 1-2 seconds I guess.

**Important Note**

My mongodb is hosted on EC2 instance which is backed by EBS volume. My Java based application is also deployed on same EC2 instance. I noticed that when I access my Java application from EC2 ip address, I am getting response for the API in milliseconds.
However when the same API is being called from localhost, it is taking more than 30 seconds to fetch the data. Note that I am connecting ec2 mongodb from localhost instead of having a local setup of mongodb on my personal computer system.

Comment: You have a lot of `DBRef` attributes. Try to disable them or set `lazy=true` to test your query performance. Please provide log details, [measure elapsed](https://www.baeldung.com/java-measure-elapsed-time#java-8) time, etc.

Comment: My mongodb is hosted on EC2 instance which is backed by EBS volume. My Java based application is also deployed on same EC2 instance. I noticed that when I access my Java application from EC2 ip address, I am getting response for the API in milliseconds.
However when the same API is being called from localhost, it is taking more than 30 seconds to fetch the data. Note that I am connecting ec2 mongodb from localhost instead of having a local setup of mongodb on my personal computer system.